# dialog does not function correctly as it meant to be

Tags: android

When i press button3(download )in my app, a download dialog box (first dialog) will appear, if i press download button in the download box, the app will check whether the data is present in my internal database. If the data is present ,the app inform user by using the second dialog box. However, the second dialog does not appear.It only appear after i relauch the button3 and the worse thing is that the first dialog appear under the second dialog, making the whole thing messy.

```
 button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dbhandler = new mydbhandler(getContext(), null, null, 1);


                if (alertdialog("download", "no thanks")) {
                    if (dbhandler.checkDatabase(movielist1.get(position).getLocation())) {
                        alertdialog1("The map is already in your internal database", "ok", "check it out!");
                    }


                    if (!dbhandler.checkDatabase(movielist1.get(position).getLocation())) {


                        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                        buffer.append(day + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + year);
                        String date = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
                        String b = "Date: " + buffer + "\n" + "Time: " + "" + date + "\n";

                        products products = new products(movielist1.get(position).getLocation(), String.valueOf(movielist1.get(position).getVersion()), b);


                        dbhandler.addProduct(products);




                    }

                }
            }


        });
```

[image]

Comment: Provide a screenshot for better understanding

Comment: @jas provided screenshot